# Confusion p.t. modulo notation in a proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

My text posed the following question (*priorly asked on Math StackExchange*): Prove that the square of any integer has one of the forms $3k$  or $3k + 1$, $k \in ℤ$,  and provided the answer:

[image]

To which I had two questions, the second of greater import:

1. What informs us to conclude that if $x^2$ is congruent to $0$ or $1$ mod$3$, then  $x$ is congruent to  $0, 1$ or $2$ mod$3$?
2. I do not understand the notation the author provided. What does $x^2 ≡ 0^2$ signify (i.e. without the mod), and how did she obtain that response from $x ≡ 0$ mod$3$ ? Moreover, how does one get from $x^2 ≡ 0^2$ to $x^2 ≡ 0^2 = 0$ mod$3$?

My appreciation in advance.

Comment: I'm sure this notation is defined earlier in your textbook.

Comment: The notation $a\equiv b\pmod n$ is equivalent to saying that $n$ divides $a-b$; in other words, $a$ and $b$ are congruent modulo $n$, ie, they represent the same equivalence class in the set of integers modulo $n$ (denoted by $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$)

Comment: I recommend that you start with reading about the basics of modular arithmetic and properties on modular equivalence, for example $a\equiv b\pmod n$ implies $a^m\equiv b^m\pmod n$, etc

Comment: Have you yet studied modular arithmetic or congruences?

Answer (score 1):

1. We are concluding the converse:  if $x$ is congruent to $0, 1,$ or $2 \pmod 3$, then $x^2$ is congruent to $0$ or $1 \pmod 3.$  Note that for all $x \in \mathbb Z,$ $x$ is congruent to $0, 1,$ or $2 \pmod 3$.  Therefore, by considering these three cases, it is proved that, for all $x \in \mathbb Z,$ $x^2$ is congruent to $0$ or $1 \pmod 3$.
2. When the text says $x$ is congruent to $0$ or $1 \pmod 3$, that is a short-cut for saying $x$ is congruent to $0 \pmod 3$ or $x$ is congruent to $1 \pmod 3.$  $0^2 = 0 \times 0 = 0.$